# Loop through a list of word documents and export a table in each document into worksheets 3,4,and 5 in my master workbook.

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master workbook with 5 worksheets.  My goal is look into a folder that has 3 word documents and open them one at a time.  Once the first word document is open I want to copy Table(2) in the word document and paste it into Worksheet 3 in my master workbook.  Once that is done I want to grab the second word document and copy Table(2) in that document and paste into Worksheet 4. Lastly, I want to get the third word document and copy Table(2) and paste into worksheet 5.

I wrote code that has several loops, however, it opens the first word document and paste Table(2) into worksheet 3 and then just keeps looping through the same word document.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim FileName As Variant
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document


FolderPath = "C:\Users\Excel Practice\"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xml*")

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True



Do While FileName <> ""

   Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
    wdDoc.Activate

    With wdDoc


    Set wrdTbl = .Tables(2)

    ColCount = wrdTbl.Columns.Count
    RowCount = wrdTbl.Rows.Count

       For c = 3 To 5
            For i = 1 To RowCount
                For j = 1 To ColCount
                    Worksheets("c").Cells(i, j) = wrdTbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Text

                Next j
            Next i
        Next c
    End With

wdDoc.Close Savechanges:=False

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: It's because of while loop you are using, while loop will just iterate but won't increment your variable, Use For each.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only open the file at the start of your code. You then loop through all 3 worksheets with a for loop from c=3 to 5. This will call the Documents.Open() function only once and copy that data to all 3 worksheets. Instead, do as @Siva suggested and iterate through the files with a foreach loop. This should do the trick.

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim fldr As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Sub getTables()
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Excel Practice\")
    sheetIndex = 3 'index of the 3rd worksheet in your workbook
    For Each file In fldr.Files
        If file.Type = "Microsoft Word Document" Then
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex) ' set active worksheet
            Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(file.Path) 'open word document
            Set wrdTbl = wdDoc.Tables(2)
            ColCount = wrdTbl.Columns.Count
            RowCount = wrdTbl.Rows.Count
            For i = 1 To RowCount
                For j = 1 To ColCount
                    ws.Cells(i, j) = wrdTbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Text
                Next j
            Next i
            sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1 ' increment worksheet index
        End If
    Next file
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Trevor, what if the folder contains 3 word documents and a number of other excel files.  Would I use Set fldr = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\idene\Desktop\WordVBA" & "*.xml*") to grab just  the xml documents